How do I create a workspace in kivymd to add and work with multiple photos at the same time?
Help, I'm making a photo editor on kivymd. I need to add a workspace to the kivymd application, namely the "WorkSpace" widget, so that I can add and work with multiple photos.
It is necessary that the user can change the position and size of the images.
It is necessary that the coordinates and dimensions of the images in this workspace are stored in python.
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.gridlayout import MDGridLayout
from kivymd.uix.anchorlayout import MDAnchorLayout
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RotateBehavior
from kivymd.uix.expansionpanel import MDExpansionPanel
from kivymd.uix.list import MDListItemTrailingIcon
from kivymd.uix.button import MDButton




class UpMenu(MDBoxLayout):
    def clicker_func(self, instance):
        print(instance.text + " was clicked")

class UpLowerMenu(MDBoxLayout):
    pass

class WorkBackGround(MDBoxLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(MDApp):
    pass

class ReadySolutions(MDBoxLayout):
    pass

class WorkSpace(MDBoxLayout):
    pass

class LayoutForVertical(MDBoxLayout):
    pass

class Properties(MDGridLayout):
    pass

class GroupsLayers(MDBoxLayout):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()

I do not know which library to use, because most work with only 1 image or there are problems with adding to the kivymd window.
